# The device name is displayed as '??'

Tags: actions-on-google

The registered device is displayed on the Google Home. 
If the device name is in Korean, it is displayed as '??'.
Do I need encoding?
If encoding is required, which should I use?

```
SyncResponse.Payload.Device.Builder deviceBuilder =
                    new SyncResponse.Payload.Device.Builder ()
                            .setId (deviceId)
                            .setType (deviceType)
                            .setTraits (traits)
                            .setAttributes (Attributes)
                            .setName (DeviceProto.DeviceNames.newBuilder ()
                                    .addAllDefaultNames (new ArrayList <> (Arrays.asList (String.valueOf (appType))))
                                    .setName ("키티")
                                    .addAllNicknames (new ArrayList <> (Arrays.asList ("키티")))
                                    .build ())
                            .setWillReportState (true)
                            .setCustomData (new JSONObject (customData));

            payloadDevices.add (deviceBuilder.build ());
```

Comment: What language is your device?

Answer (score 0):

You could try encoding the characters in unicode and pass then as UTF-8 encoded:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] {(byte)0xed, (byte)0x82, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0xed, (byte)0x8b, (byte)0xb0};
String name = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

But that most likely will result in the same question marks. There are a lot of placed for the encoding to fail, conversion to JSON contents, google api's not supporting foreign languages and much more.